# Can't convert argument to finish program

Tags: c++, winapi, multiprocessing, beginthreadex

I am working on a class project and trying to use `_beginthreadex` as part of a multiprocessing project.

This is the trouble spot. I have this function that I call when using `_beginthreadex`:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadWork(LPVOID threadNo)
{
    int threadID = *(int*)threadNo;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberIter; i++)
```

and I call the function here:

```
threadIDs[i] = i;
threads[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadWork, &threadIDs[i], 0, NULL);
```

but I keep receiving this error:

> 'uintptr_t _beginthreadex(void *,unsigned int,_beginthreadex_proc_type,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int *)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'DWORD (__cdecl *)(LPVOID)' to '_beginthreadex_proc_type'

I have done a lot of searching on this topic, and am still very confused and cannot find a solution. I tried replacing `LPVOID threadNo` with `void *` as per another thread, but that did not solve my issue. I am assuming it is a pointer issue, but I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Don't use the windows API for that (who taught you that?). use [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), or when you want the thread to calculate something use [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). And then you can use [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to pass functions and capture variables by value and/or reference explicitly. Also when you use multithreading learn about std::mutex/std::scoped_lock/std::condition_variable and std::unique_lock

Comment: Have you read [the `_beginthreadex` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=msvc-170)?

Comment: Sadly, part of the purpose of this project is learning to use the Win 32 API and multiprocessing.

Comment: *I have done a lot of searching on this topic* -- The error is very clear in that the third parameter does not match what is to be expected.

Comment: I was following the provided material for the project and had not read the _beginthreadex documentation. I now see where the DWORD function differs from the documentation. Thank you both!

Comment: Admittedly, the Visual C++ compiler error messages when it comes to mismatch of the function signatures for function pointers was always lacking.  If the error message had `typedef unsigned (__stdcall* _beginthreadex_proc_type)(void*);` in it instead of just `_beginthread_proc_type`, the error would not only be clearer, but more obvious than it is now.

Comment: If you would like to learn to use the Win32 API and multiprocessing, you may need [Using Processes and Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/using-processes-and-threads) as @RemyLebeau answered.

Answer (score 2):

`_beginthreadex()` is part of Microsoft's C library runtime, not the Win32 API. But you are trying to use a Win32-style callback with it (specifically, a [`ThreadProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85)) callback for [`CreateThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread)).

If you read the [`_beginthreadex()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=msvc-170), it tells you the correct signature to use for your callback:

```cpp
unsigned ( __stdcall *start_address )( void * )
```

So, use this instead:

```cpp
unsigned __stdcall threadWork(void* argument)
{
    int threadNo = *(int*)argument;
    ...
}

threadIDs[i] = i;
threads[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadWork, &threadIDs[i], 0, NULL);
```

But, if your goal really is "learning to use the Win 32 API" then use [`CreateThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) instead:

```cpp
DWORD WINAPI threadWork(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    int threadNo = *(int*)lpParameter;
    ...
}

threadIDs[i] = i;
threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadWork, &threadIDs[i], 0, NULL);
```

That being said, since your question is tagged [c++], you really should use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) or [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) instead (unless you are stuck using a pre-2011 compiler):

```cpp
void threadWork(int threadNo)
{
    ...
}

threads[i] = std::thread(threadWork, i);
```

Comment: I wonder why everyone skips `std::jthread`!

Comment: @Red.Wave Probably because C++20 isn't as common yeet as C++11 or C++17.